# How to migrate to a controller-less AngularJS design pattern?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive, controller, angularjs-scope

It seems that there is a trend in eschewing designs which lend themselves to massive and unruly controllers for a more directive-based, granular design pattern--Angular 2 seems to be promoting this direction as well. I, admittedly, have rather large, non-DRY controllers in my angular apps, and wish to start using angular without relying on massive controllers and page-level scopes, but when I think about simply using directives for everything that I would have stuck in a controller the prospect of initiating and maintaining communication between relevant scopes, controlling scope inheritance, and keeping directives as modular as possible seems like I'm just thinking of directives as tiny, isolated controllers with an attached scope. Is this the wrong way to view this angular design pattern shift? How can I properly think about designing with directives if I am used to holding much of the logic in services / controllers? Is this still MVC or MVVW?